# Different MKPinAnnotation for different data

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have 3 types of locations.

I'm getting the data from my server, then I'm parsing it and displaying the locations on the mapView.

I want to display different colors for the different types of data. 3 types = 3 colors.

How can I control this?

Comment: Try this,

     annotation1.subtitle = @"1st annotation";
     annotation2.subtitle = @"2st annotation";
     annotation3.subtitle = @"3st annotation";
       
     Check annotation
     if ([annotation.subtitle isEqualToString:@"1st annotation"])
     {
       //change  color
      }

    else if ([annotation.subtitle isEqualToString:@"2st annotation"])
     {
       //change  color
      }
     else if ([annotation.subtitle isEqualToString:@"3st annotation"])
     {
       //change  color
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method for doing this.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[yourAnnotationLocation class]])
    {

        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            //if you need image you can set it like
            //annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];//here we use a nice image instead of the default pins
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        if ([annotation.title isEqualToString:@"Midhun"])
        {
             annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        }
        return annotationView;
    }

return nil;
}
```

For setting custom property to your annotation add a class which confirms to `MKAnnotation` protocol.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyLocation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *_name;
    NSString *_address;
    int _yourValue;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
}

@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (copy) NSString *address;
@property (assign) yourValue;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

This is is a nice [**tutorial**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial).

Comment: I don't want to check if the titles are equal, because there are many titles.

Comment: @YosiDahan: it's an example, you can check your type there

Comment: the type is a value that each object in the array has. how can I assaign each annotation its type?

Comment: You need to subclass MKAnnotation, and add a property in that class for holding the value

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this,
 annotation1.subtitle = @"1st annotation"; 
     annotation2.subtitle = @"2st annotation"; 
       annotation3.subtitle = @"3st annotation";
    Check annotation 
       if ([annotation.subtitle isEqualToString:@"1st annotation"]) 
       { 
          //change color 
         }
          else if ([annotation.subtitle isEqualToString:@"2st annotation"])
          { 
           //change color 
                 } 
         else if ([annotation.subtitle isEqualToString:@"3st annotation"]) 
          { 
          //change color 
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something with latitude and longitude comparison

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation { static NSString *identifier = @"yourIdentifier";  
MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
if([annotation coordinate].latitude==YourLocationLatitude)
{

    pin.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag-red.png"];
}
else
{
    pin.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag-green.png"];
}}
```